# Detección de caracteres incorrecta en proyecto de OCR

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr

estoy haciendo un proyecto de reconocimiento de texto de un DNI, usando Visual Studio 2015, OpenCV y el método KNN de reconocimiento de caracteres.

Para ello he recortado directamente los campos de interés para simplificar el proceso y he realizado el proceso de reconocimiento a cada uno de ellos.

He obtenido buenos resultados pero me confunde una M por una N y las O con 0.

Sabéis como podría solucionarlo? Gracias!

Aquí os dejo el código con el campo en el que obtengo el fallo

Código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\ml\ml.hpp>

#include "Preproceso.h"

// VARIABLES GLOBALES  
/////////////////////////////////////////////
const int AREA_MINIMA_DE_CONTORNO = 70;
const int ANCHO_IMAGEN_REDIM = 20;
const int ALTURA_IMAGEN_REDIM = 30;

class ContornoConDatos {
public:
// variables miembro 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
std::vector<cv::Point> ptContorno;
cv::Rect rectanguloDelimitador;
float fltAreaDelContorno;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
bool comprobarSiContornoValido() {
    if (fltAreaDelContorno < AREA_MINIMA_DE_CONTORNO) return false;
    return true;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
static bool ordenarPosicionXRectDelim(const ContornoConDatos& ccdIzquierda, 
const ContornoConDatos&
    ccdDerecha) {
    return(ccdIzquierda.rectanguloDelimitador.x < ccdDerecha.rectanguloDelimitador.x);
}
};

         //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void preprocess(cv::Mat &imagenOriginal, cv::Mat &imagenEscalaDeGrises, cv::Mat &imagenUmbralizada) {

imagenEscalaDeGrises = extraerValor(imagenOriginal);

cv::Mat imagenMaxContrasteEscalaDeGrises = maximizarContraste(imagenEscalaDeGrises);

cv::Mat imagenSuavizada;

cv::GaussianBlur(imagenMaxContrasteEscalaDeGrises, imagenSuavizada, TAMAÑO_FILTRO_SUAVE_GAUSSIANO, 0);

cv::adaptiveThreshold(imagenSuavizada, imagenUmbralizada, 255.0, CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV, TAMAÑO_BLOQUE_UMBRAL, ANCHO_UMBRAL);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

cv::Mat extraerValor(cv::Mat &imagenOriginal) {
cv::Mat imagenHSV;
std::vector<cv::Mat> vectorDeImagenesHSV(2);
cv::Mat imagenValor;

cv::cvtColor(imagenOriginal, imagenHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);

cv::split(imagenHSV, vectorDeImagenesHSV);

imagenValor = vectorDeImagenesHSV[2];

return(imagenValor);
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
cv::Mat maximizarContraste(cv::Mat &imagenEscalaDeGrises) {
cv::Mat imagenTopHat;
cv::Mat imagenBlackHat;
cv::Mat imagenEscalaDeGrisesMasTopHat;
cv::Mat imagenEscalaDeGrisesMasTopHatMenosBlackHat;

cv::Mat structuringElement = cv::getStructuringElement(CV_SHAPE_RECT, cv::Size(3, 3));

cv::morphologyEx(imagenEscalaDeGrises, imagenTopHat, CV_MOP_TOPHAT, structuringElement);
cv::morphologyEx(imagenEscalaDeGrises, imagenBlackHat, CV_MOP_BLACKHAT, structuringElement);

imagenEscalaDeGrisesMasTopHat = imagenEscalaDeGrises + imagenTopHat;
imagenEscalaDeGrisesMasTopHatMenosBlackHat = imagenEscalaDeGrisesMasTopHat - imagenBlackHat;

return(imagenEscalaDeGrisesMasTopHatMenosBlackHat);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
cv::Ptr<cv::ml::KNearest> kNearest(cv::ml::KNearest::create());

// read in training classifications 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
cv::Mat matrizClasificacionCaracteres;
cv::FileStorage archivoClasificacion("classifications.xml", cv::FileStorage::READ);
if (archivoClasificacion.isOpened() == false) {
    std::cout << "error, unable to open training classifications file, exiting program\n\n";
    return(0);
}
archivoClasificacion["classifications"] >> matrizClasificacionCaracteres;
archivoClasificacion.release();

// read in training images 
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
cv::Mat matrizPixelesImagenReferencia;
cv::FileStorage archivoImagenes("images.xml", cv::FileStorage::READ);
if (archivoImagenes.isOpened() == false) {
    std::cout << "error, unable to open training images file, exiting program\n\n";
    return(0);
}
archivoImagenes["images"] >> matrizPixelesImagenReferencia;
archivoImagenes.release();

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//entrenamiento

//cv::Ptr<cv::ml::KNearest> kNearest(cv::ml::KNearest::create());

kNearest->setDefaultK(1);

kNearest->train(matrizPixelesImagenReferencia, cv::ml::ROW_SAMPLE, matrizClasificacionCaracteres);


//Leer la imagen base, de la cual obtengo solamente las dimensiones para asignarselas a mi verdadera imagen, con la que voy a trabajar
cv::Mat imagenBase = cv::imread("ImagenBase.png");
if (imagenBase.empty()) {
    std::cout << "No se puede leer la imagen del archivo \n\n";
    return (0);
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Leer la imagen con la que voy a trabajar, a la cual le realizo el cambio de dimension
cv::Mat imagenOriginal = cv::imread("DNI-Jessica.jpg");

//cv::Mat imagenOriginal = cv::imread("DNI.png");
if (imagenOriginal.empty()) {
    std::cout << "No se puede leer la imagen del archivo \n\n";
    return (0);
}

// Redimensionar imagenOriginal al tamaño de imagenBase para que todas las imagenes de entrada tengan las mismas dimensiones
cv::resize(imagenOriginal, imagenOriginal, imagenBase.size());
cv::imshow("ImagenOriginal", imagenOriginal);


//////Sección de interés 2: SEGUNDO APELLIDO///////////////////////////////
cv::Rect dimensionesROI2(255, 128, 300, 30);
//cv::Rect dimensionesROI2(250, 125, 300, 30);
//Recortar la imagen original para obtener ROI2
cv::Mat ROI2 = imagenOriginal(dimensionesROI2);

//PRE-PROCESADO DE LA IMAGEN/////////////////////////////////////////////

cv::Mat imagenEscalaDeGrises2;
cv::Mat imagenSuavizada2;
cv::Mat imagenUmbralizada2;


preprocess(ROI2, imagenSuavizada2, imagenUmbralizada2);

cv::threshold(imagenUmbralizada2, imagenUmbralizada2, 0.0, 255.0, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);

cv::Mat imagenDeTrabajo2 = imagenUmbralizada2.clone();

cv::imshow("Imagen pre-procesada 2", imagenUmbralizada2);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

std::vector<ContornoConDatos> todosLosContornos2;
std::vector<ContornoConDatos> contornosValidos2;

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > ptContornos2;
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> v4iJerarquia2;

cv::findContours(imagenDeTrabajo2, ptContornos2, v4iJerarquia2, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

for (int i = 0; i < ptContornos2.size(); i++)
{
    ContornoConDatos contornoConDatos2;
    contornoConDatos2.ptContorno = ptContornos2[i];
    contornoConDatos2.rectanguloDelimitador = cv::boundingRect(contornoConDatos2.ptContorno);
    contornoConDatos2.fltAreaDelContorno = cv::contourArea(contornoConDatos2.ptContorno);
    todosLosContornos2.push_back(contornoConDatos2);
}

for (int i = 0; i < todosLosContornos2.size(); i++)
{
    if (todosLosContornos2[i].comprobarSiContornoValido())
    {
        contornosValidos2.push_back(todosLosContornos2[i]);
    }
}

std::sort(contornosValidos2.begin(), contornosValidos2.end(), ContornoConDatos::ordenarPosicionXRectDelim);
std::string strCadenaFinal2;

for (int i = 0; i < contornosValidos2.size(); i++)
{
    cv::rectangle(ROI2, contornosValidos2[i].rectanguloDelimitador, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);

    cv::Mat imagenROI2 = imagenUmbralizada2(contornosValidos2[i].rectanguloDelimitador);

    cv::Mat imagenROIRedimensionada2;

    cv::resize(imagenROI2, imagenROIRedimensionada2, cv::Size(ANCHO_IMAGEN_REDIM, ALTURA_IMAGEN_REDIM));

    cv::Mat matrizROIDatosTipoReal2;

    imagenROIRedimensionada2.convertTo(matrizROIDatosTipoReal2, CV_32FC1);

    cv::Mat matrizROIConRealesSimples2 = matrizROIDatosTipoReal2.reshape(1, 1);

    cv::Mat vectorCaracterActual2(0, 0, CV_32F);

    kNearest->findNearest(matrizROIConRealesSimples2, 1, vectorCaracterActual2);

    float fltCaracterActual2 = (float)vectorCaracterActual2.at<float>(0, 0);
    strCadenaFinal2 = strCadenaFinal2 + char(int(fltCaracterActual2));
}

std::cout << "\n" << "SEGUNDO APELLIDO = " << strCadenaFinal2 << "\n";

cv::imshow("SEGUNDO APELLIDO", ROI2);
```

Comment: Hola Jessica. Para discernir los ceros de las O's quizá podrias recurrir a la coherencia. Por ejemplo en nombres no hay numeros y en los identificadores solo en ciertas partes hay. Un saludo

Comment: Te refieres a separar en la base de datos qué son números y qué son letras y luego especificarlo de nuevo en cada campo? Gracias!

Comment: Si, utilizar algun tipo de mascara para ID's y luego en campos de Nombres y así sustituir los `0` por `O's`

Answer (score 2):

Si estás trabajando con [DNI Españoles](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNI_electr%C3%B3nico_en_Espa%C3%B1a), puedes realizar unos sencillos cambios que si bien no solucionarán el problema del reconocimiento incorrecto de caracteres, reducirán los errores.

---

Partamos de la base que el documento fotografiado es real, si no: no tendrías digitalización del mismo. Sabemos que un DNI Español sigue el patrón de 8 números y una letra, siendo la letra el último carácter del código; así pues: si detectas una `O` en una posición que no es la última, sin duda será un `0` y si detectas un `0` en la última posición será sin duda una `O`.

Respecto a confundir `M` y `N`, puedes discernir qué letra le corresponde siguiendo el [algoritmo del dígito de control](http://www.interior.gob.es/ca/web/servicios-al-ciudadano/dni/calculo-del-digito-de-control-del-nif-nie):

> El artículo 11 del Real Decreto 1553/2005, de 23 de  diciembre, establece que el Documento Nacional de Identidad recogerá el número personal del DNI y carácter de verificación correspondiente al número de Identificación Fiscal.
>
> - Para verificar el NIF de españoles residentes mayores de edad, el algoritmo de cálculo del dígito de control es el siguiente:
>
> Se divide el número entre 23 y el resto se sustituye por una letra que se determina por inspección mediante la siguiente tabla:
>
> ```
> |RESTO |0  |1  |2  |3  |4  |5  |6  |7  |8  |9  |10 |11|
> |LETRA |T  |R  |W  |A  |G  |M  |Y  |F  |P  |D  |X  |B |
>
> |RESTO |12 |13 |14 |15 |16 |17 |18 |19 |20 |21 |22 |
> |LETRA |N  |J  |Z  |S  |Q  |V  |H  |L  |C  |K  |E  |
> ```

Así pues, este sencillo algoritmo te indicará, dado el nº de DNI, la letra que le corresponde:

```
char Letra(int DNI)
{
    constexpr char letra[] {'T', 'R', 'W', 'A', 'G', 'M', 'Y', 'F', 'P', 'D', 'X', 'B', 'N', 'J', 'Z', 'S', 'Q', 'V', 'H', 'L', 'C', 'K', 'E'};
    return letra[DNI % 23];
}
```

Por lo tanto, tras realizar el reconocimiento de caracteres, verificas que el nº de DNI obtenido tenga la letra correcta; si falla la verificación con `N` comprueba si la pasa con `M` y viceversa.

---

Editado.

> El sitio donde me da más error es en los campos de texto de Nombre y Apellidos, que no hay números, ¿Sabes como podría establecer que en esos campos solo hay letras?

En primer lugar, es posible que los campos de Nombre y Apellidos contengan letras, tenemos el caso de [Jennifer 8 Lee](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_8._Lee), una periodista cuyo primer apellido es el número 8. También se conoce el caso de [Brfxxccxxmnpcccclllmmnprxvclmnckssqlbb11116](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brfxxccxxmnpcccclllmmnprxvclmnckssqlbb11116) (pronunciado «Albin») un Sueco cuyo nombre contiene 5 números.

Sin ser experto en OCR no te puedo dar buenos consejos al respecto, pero lo que yo personalmente haría sería hacer varios pases del algoritmo de reconocimiento de caracteres con diferentes parámetros (y diferentes orientaciones de la imagen) y comparar los resultados entre si, quedándome con los caracteres con más coincidencias. Por ejemplo:

Nombre `Priscilo`

- Pase1: `Prisci10`
- Pase2: `Priscilo`
- Pase3: `Pri5ci10`
- Pase4: `Priscilo`
- Pase5: `Pri5cilo`
- Pase6: `Priscilo`

Vemos que las tres primeras letras coinciden 6 de 6 veces; así que las consideramos válidas. La cuarta letra tiene 4/6 `s` y 2/6 `5`, usaremos `s` entonces. La 5ª y 6ª letra coinciden 6 de 6 veces, las usaremos tal cual también...

¿Puede ser de ayuda?

Comment: Vale muchísimas gracias! De todos modos el sitio donde me da más error es en los campos de texto de Nombre y Apellidos, que no hay números, sabes como podría establecer que en esos campos solo hay letras?